# Search a text in all the files in tgz

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, sh

Unix Scripting

Create a Unix Script which can do :
1) Search a text in all the files in tgz
2) Search for FileName in all the files in tgz
and creates a separate archive file containing the result."

The script should be able to table below params :

```
scriptname ""text"" ""file.tgz"" ""user""
```

output in /var/tmp/user/result_[time].tgz
result file should have all files containing the text provided.

```
scriptname ""FileName"" ""file.tgz"" ""user""
```

output in /var/tmp/user/result_{time}.tgz
result tgz should have all the files matching the name"

Comment: Did you try anything or are you trying to hire a coder?

Comment: I am aware of searching the text and file but I am new to shell scripting so I need a approach how can start. How can I take input from user etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started:

```
$ cat foo.txt                         # two test files
foo
baz
$ cat bar.txt
bar
baz
$ tar czvf test.tar.gz *.txt          # tar and gzip them
$ mkdir temp                          # working dir
$ cd temp                             # work in it
```

A script to *Search a text* (`foo`) *in all the files in tgz* (`test.tar.gz`).

```
$ OIFS=$IFS
$ IFS=$'\n'                           # handle space in filenames     
$ for i in $(tar tzf ../test.tar.gz)  # list files in the tar and for loop them
  do 
    tar xzf ../test.tar.gz "$i"       # extract each file individually
    grep -l foo "$i"                  # grep for string foo in each file
    rm -f $i                          # rm extracted file
  done
foo.txt                               # the output
$ IFS=$OIFS
```

Comment: Thanks For you help i will work on this and keep you posted with the progess

Comment: You could also do `for i in $(tar tzf test.tar.gz); do tar xzOf test.tar.gz "$i" | grep -1 "foo" >/dev/null && echo "$i"; done` and avoid messing with `IFS`, creating the file and the subsequent `rm`. (using the `-O --to-stdout` option to pipe the file contents to `grep`)